# Cyrillic and other characters show as numerals enclosed in \ slashes

Tags: character-encoding

When I use Cyrillic characters, a pound sign (£), degree sign and others, they appear as figures enclosed by forward slashes when I open the file again. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a sequence of 3 octal numerals preceded by a backslash? Or do you really mean a sequence of "figures" (numerals?) *enclosed* by two backslashes?

If the former, you're likely seeing a character's code represented in octal form.

1. In that case, first see if the value of variable `ctl-arrow` is `nil`, and if so whether changing the value to non-`nil` helps. `C-h v ctl-arrow`:

> `ctl-arrow` is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means display control chars with uparrow.
>
> A value of `nil` means use backslash and octal digits.
> This variable does not apply to characters whose display is specified
> in the current display table (if there is one).
>
> You can customize this variable.

2. Second, try a different font - perhaps your font just can't display those particular Cyrillic characters.
3. Read the Emacs manual, node [Text Display](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Display.html), where it says this:

> The raw bytes with codes `U+0080` (octal 200) through `U+009F` (octal 237) are displayed as “octal escape sequences”, with the `escape-glyph` face.  For instance, character code ‘U+0098’ (octal 230) is displayed as `\230`.  If you change the buffer-local variable `ctl-arrow` to `nil`, the ASCII control characters are also displayed as octal escape sequences instead of caret escape sequences.

4. See also the Elisp manual, node [Usual Display](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Usual-Display.html), where it says this:

> “Raw bytes” are non-ASCII characters with codes 128 through 255 (See Text Representations).  These characters display as “octal escapes”: sequences of four glyphs, where the first glyph is the ASCII code for `\`, and the others are digit characters representing the character code in octal.  (A display table can specify a glyph to use instead of `\`.)